# how tobuild url request with get method using alamofire

Tags: ios, swift4

I am not aware of building api with dynamic values.I have an api and from that, i want to get pluscode by sending url request with latitude, longitude and email to base url.My requirement is sending request in get method with lat,long and email values and getting pluscode from response.Can anyone help me to build this url.

```
     lat = locValue.latitude
      long = locValue.longitude
    email = abcdefg@gmail.com

    //base url 
    var pluscodeurl = "https://plus.codes/api?address="

let postParameters = ["address":lat+long ,"email":"mahithaa.angadi@gmail.com"] as [String : Any]

        Alamofire.request(pluscodeurl, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {  response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)

            case .failure(_):
                break

            }

        }
```

Comment: Did you try anything? That's a basic use of Alamofire: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#get-request-with-url-encoded-parameters

Comment: please have a look above..i have mentioned my request

Comment: Do you need to send the parameters as Dictionary object or you want to send them in the url ? Because you have not used the postParameters Dictionary.

Comment: i want to send them along with url ..i mean in url

Comment: Please try this: var pluscodeurl = "https://plus.codes/api?address=" + lat + "," + long + "?email=" + email
Append them in the url and make a single string from them rather then creating a dictionary

Comment: Here it is : https://plus.codes/api?address=23.0225,72.5714

Comment: email should be static value..

Comment: Then pass the email as below:
var pluscodeurl = "https://plus.codes/api?address=" + lat + "," + long + "?email=abc@gmail.com"

Comment: @AnshulBhatheja getting an error "Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Double'"

Comment: Put the whole code in a single double quotes like this:
var pluscodeurl = "https://plus.codes/api?address=\(lat),\(long)&email=abc@gmail.com"

Comment: I will put this in an answer. Please check my answer below.

Comment: thankyou ..its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the snippet you can write it

```
        let lat = "19.0760"
        let long = "72.8777"
        let email = "abc@test.com"
        let ApiURL = "https://plus.codes/api?address=\(lat),\(long)&email=\(email)"

        Alamofire.request(ApiURL).responseJSON { response in
            print("Result: \(response.result)")
            if let json = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(json)")
            }
            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your url in the below format:

```
let email = "abc@gmail.com"

let pluscodeurl = "https://plus.codes/api?address=\(lat),\(long)&email=\(email)"
```